# JBoss 7.1.1 wont start on Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, jboss, osx-mavericks

Trying to start JBOSS 7.1.1 on my Mac. ran standalone.sh from terminal. I get this:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
15:17:36,152 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:17:36,770 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:17:36,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Then it just sits there. My boot.log:

```
15:17:36,152 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:17:36,770 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:17:36,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
15:17:36,829 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
    [Standalone] = 
    awt.toolkit = sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    ftp.nonProxyHosts = local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
    gopherProxySet = false
    http.nonProxyHosts = local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /Users/whitehawk/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
    java.home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /var/folders/1k/g131s46s043_1zq19ds3r68r0000gn/T/
    java.library.path = /Users/whitehawk/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_05-b13
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_05
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.5-b02
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.home.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
    jboss.host.name = alexeis-macbook-air
    jboss.modules.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = alexeis-macbook-air
    jboss.qualified.host.name = alexeis-macbook-air.local
    jboss.server.base.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data
    jboss.server.default.config = standalone.xml
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/content
    jboss.server.log.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log
    jboss.server.name = alexeis-macbook-air
    jboss.server.temp.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = x86_64
    os.name = Mac OS X
    os.version = 10.9.2
    path.separator = :
    socksNonProxyHosts = local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeBig
    sun.java.command = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar -mp /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
    user.country = US
    user.country.format = CA
    user.dir = /Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin
    user.home = /Users/whitehawk
    user.language = en
    user.name = whitehawk
    user.timezone = America/Vancouver
15:17:36,837 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -D[Standalone] -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/Users/whitehawk/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run JBoss 7 on Java 8, which is untested/not supported according to some of their forum threads:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/238195

I'd recommend you download and use JDK7.